Upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04 failing at contacting the repositories with waiting for headers 0% even though apt-get update works fine
Today I'm having some issues at running do-release-upgrade in my Ubuntu 22.04. After several troubleshooting I'm stuck at not knowing what else to do. As the title mentions, the upgrade is stuck at contacting the repositories with waiting for headers 0%. sudo apt update / upgrade works fine, I can install anything without any issues.



Are you connected to the internet? 2. Can you run sudo apt update first?


Yes, apt update or upgrade runs fine. I can install anything is needed, but the upgrade does not work as I'm stuck with the waiting for headers. Any idea?

It seems that you are not connected to internet. Run ping 8.8.8.8 and post the output
